# Have some money on my plastic

Tags: word-usage

Can I say "Have some money on my plastic" meaning "I have some funds on my bank account and card is with me"?

Comment: One charges things to plastic i.e. credit cards. Credit cards do not refer to money you have. You can get cash with them, at a high interest rate.

Comment: Not all cards are credit cards; prepaid cards have funds already loaded onto them. I agree it's an unconventional usage, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can say it, and someone might guess what you mean. They might also think what you mean is you have charged something to a charge card, or that you have ample credit limit left on your charge card at the moment.

But it isn't a common usage of the phrase; it would sound slightly "off", leaving people to wonder if it somehow was a regional phrase you had picked up somewhere.

Comment: Agreed.  "I have some money on my card," would be the more common American usage.